# Display Console output to a control in app

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield, nstextview

My Cocoa app has a debug mode that displays additional window in which I'd like to present NSLog output (just like the Console window in Xcode). I already have a custom NSlog method, which saves the output to a file as well.
Which control should I use NSTextView? How to append the text inside it with a new line?
The log may be long so it needs to be efficient too. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a NSTextView, and each time that you print something with your customized log function, you append it to the text view (use a mutable string).

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSTextView. It would be easiest and most efficient.

```
[myTextView insertText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\r\n", yourStringTOAppend]];
```